# Converting column from military time to standard time

Tags: r, excel

I'm trying to convert a column showing the time of road traffic accidents from military time to standard time. The data looks like this:

```
Col1   Time..24hr.
1      1404
2      322
3      1945
4      1005
5      945
```

I'd then like to convert to 12hr so for '322' I'd like to make '3', for instance. Thanks a lot

Comment: do you want  `322` to end up as `3` or as `322`?  Are you trying to round to the nearest hour?

Comment: Ideally 322 would end up as 3, and 2045 would end up as 20

Comment: Hmm.  Thanks for the clarification, but that's not at *all* what I inferred (and I think could reasonably be inferred) from the description "convert to 12hr" or "to standard time" ... ???  I.e. I thought you would want 2045 to end up as 845 (PM) or 8 (PM).

Comment: Ahh my mistake, apologies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your criteria -- that 322 is represented as 3 and 2045 is 20 -- how about dividing by 100 and then rounding towards 0 with `trunc()`.

```
 time_24hr <- c(1404, 322, 1945, 1005, 945)
 trunc(time_24hr / 100)
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using the modulo operator `%%` ?

```
time_24hr <- c(1404,322,1945,1005,945)
time_12hr <- time_24hr %% 1200
ampm <- c("AM","PM")[(time_24hr %/% 1200) + 1]
```

(I'm not sure how this will handle noon and midnight ...)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use lubridate package as below

```
library(lubridate)
time_24hr <- c(1404, 322, 1945, 1005, 945)
hm(time_24hr / 100)
```