# Convert military time to standard time with hours and minutes in R

Tags: r, time

I have the following set of times data, that I have to convert into 12 hour format.

```
-----------------
814
830
1835
1730
1442
820
1430
930
1550
1725
1615
1010
1319
1755
820
1955
1850
710
-------------------------------------
```

For example:
1300 =  1:00 PM

I want this using R..

It would be great help if anyone tell me how shall I convert this time using R

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting column from military time to standard time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30988040/converting-column-from-military-time-to-standard-time)

Comment: Thanks for reply.. I check that links that you mentioned and it is different from my problem..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try,

```
format(strptime(substr(as.POSIXct(sprintf("%04.0f", x), 
                                 format="%H%M"), 12, 16), '%H:%M'), '%I:%M %p')

#[1] "08:14 AM" "08:30 AM" "06:35 PM" "05:30 PM" "02:42 PM" "08:20 AM"
```

**data**

```
x <- c(814, 830, 1835, 1730,1442, 820)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
myMtime #time vector
myMtime <- sprintf("%04d", myMtime)
myStdTime <- as.POSIXct(myMtime, format = "%H%M", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
myStdTime #time as unix standard for time zone UTC
```

Note that R will automatically add the year-month-day of the day you are converting `myMtime`. If you want to add a specific date, do the following:

```
myMtime #time vector
date <- "2016-01-01"
myMtime <- sprintf("%04d", myMtime)
myStdTime <- as.POSIXct(paste0(date, " ", myMtime), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H%M", origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "UTC")
myStdTime #time as unix standard for time zone UTC
```

For the output format use `format`:

```
format(myStdTime, format = "%r%p")
#or thing like that:
format(myStdTime, format = "%a %b %d %X %Y %Z")
#for further explanations consider:
?strptime
```