# Converting the hourly numeric value into standard date hour

Tags: r

I am new to R and I am trying to convert numeric column(Hour) where standard hour value is present into standard hour time format.

```
hour_df
-------+
Hour   |
-------+
100    |
2315   |
2000   |
1236   |
25     |
1800   |
600    |
165    |
-------+
```

What I am trying to convert is Hour column as time format

```
-------+
Hour   |
-------+
01:00  |
23:15  |
20:00  |
12:36  |
00:25  |
18:00  |
06:00  |
01:65  |
-------+
```

Comment: Duplicate of [Convert military time to standard time with hours and minutes in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433156/convert-military-time-to-standard-time-with-hours-and-minutes-in-r)

Comment: By the way your last value is `01:65`. Not that it matters but it can ruin heavily OCD people :)

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sprintf` to format to a 4 digit number by padding 0 at the left, then insert a `:` after the first two digits with regex

```
sub("^(.{2})", "\\1:", sprintf("%04d", hour_df$Hour))
```